# How can I run a full-featured Linux distro in docker?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker

I'd like to a Linux shell in the cloud to administer my cloud infrastructure from.  I want modcons like man pages and lots of utility programs.  I plan to access it with ssh and have ssh-agent forward my private keys.  It would be nice to start from a stock Ubuntu image and just add what I need using a Dockerfile.  But the standard Ubuntu images on dockerhub are stripped down.  Can I easily achieve what I want?  Or am I asking for the wrong thing?

An alternative that works OK is using a traditional VM.  The disadvantages of that are that they take longer to build, provisioning is a bit more complex than writing a Dockerfile, and you pay for each one, whereas with docker I can run as many of these admin containers as I want.

Comment: You might be interested in [these docker tips](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/07/12/10-docker-tips-and-tricks-that-will-make-you-sing-a-whale-song-of-joy/) posted by a dev at docker. He describes using containers as disposable dev environments that can use the host's docker daemon among other things.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I will take some ideas from that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker ontainers are intended to run single applications. You might want to look into native LXC containers. They are capable of running full a OS.

Comment: OK, I guess this is the true answer.  It would be cool if docker expanded to allow running full OS's since docker is becoming so popular and convenient while LXC containers are more intimidating.

Answer (score 1):

This is against idea behind Docker, you are not supposed to administer your containers from inside, if you want to change your container you throw it away and rebuild it again.

See blog post [Docker Best Practices](http://blog.bigstep.com/big-data-performance/docker-best-practices/)

Comment: I never said I wanted to fiddle with running containers.  I just want a shell in the cloud so that I can build and deploy containers.  Currently I am using a local shell, but it is really slow to send build context.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is about. Rent any traditional VM in the cloud and you'll get a shell.

Comment: That is true.  I tried to explain in the question that that approach has drawbacks -- basically the drawbacks that full VMs always have vis-a-vis containers.  I will use full VMs if docker doesn't currently support my use case, but I don't see any reason why it couldn't or shouldn't support it.

Comment: It's a good idea to run docker on a VPS as you can often get better push/pull performance.